# How to make a horitonzal sliding infinite animation using CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make an infinite horizontal slider with 3 rows of images.

It looks like this:
[image]

But as you see when the end of the rows of images arrive, there's a huge blank space while the image finally appears again.

You can test it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbergeron/q596y/6/

Here's the CSS behind it:

```
ul.lists {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 180s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    moveSlideshow 180s linear infinite;
}

ul.lists li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.lists li img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

ul.slider2 {
    top: 140px;
}

ul.slider3 {
    top: 280px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0%   {
        -moz-transform:    translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform:    translateX(-300%);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to happen is to never see that blank space, I would like it to roll on forever. Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this behavior?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: I take it a JS solution wouldn't be optimal? One thought is to split the row of images into two halves, each longer than the page width, and apply different animations to each so that once the first is off screen it will appear back on screen behind the second one?

Comment: I have found an [infinite css carousel](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-responsive-carousel/), you may be able to adapt it: [DEMO](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2629908/sandbox/fluid-css-carousel/index.html)

Comment: As long as it's responsive on all platforms I don't mind adding some js in there. Thanks for the explanation @LcLk that's a good start. I'll check that carousel maybe I can dig something from it thanks!

Comment: hi, any feed back would be nice :) .... ze clone idea: http://jsfiddle.net/q596y/8/

Answer (score 1):

basicly , You need to clone your elements.

At least many enough of the first ones to fill the entire width of the screen,  or split into two differents tags, your elements.

So once a part of them, is gone left, you move them back to the right end to fill that empty space to keep scrolling without any gaps.

Your case requires javascript.

So many images wrapping line by line needs to clone the whole `ul`.

A good compromise could be to split content  within two `ul`, so one can to next once of screen.

To duplicate the whole `ul` in the HTML document might not be a good idea and i would not advise to do so for text.

jQuery **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q596y/8/)** of your fiddle.

```
$(".lists.slider1").clone().appendTo("body");
$(".lists.slider2").clone().appendTo("body");
$(".lists.slider3").clone().appendTo("body");
```

---

But for small "marquee like" , you can use pseudo elements to clone the first few images.

For text of a known length(em) or known container's width  , you may use text-shadow.

Pseudo and text-shadow avoid duplication of content.

Some horrible CSS example that demonstrate the cloning idea: http://dabblet.com/gist/5656795

Comment: I have no javascript ready to use nor known ressources you could use. Somebody else might :)